# What happens if I look too suspicious?

Tags: fallen-london

I know that if I spend enough time without doing anything suspicious, things calm down, but what happens if I'm too suspicious? Will I return to prison?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each of the Primary Menaces (Nightmares, Scandal, Wounds, and Suspicion) there is a consequence upon reaching level 8 with any of them.

For Suspicion, once you reach Level 8, you are hauled back to New Newgate Prison, where you'll be stuck until you reduce your Suspicion to 0.

Before that reach that point, however, you will notice some other events related to high Suspicion.

For instance, once your Suspicion reaches 4, you'll see the "Find a way to throw the Constables off the scent" Storylet appear at your lodgings, and give you an opportunity to ask your friends for help.

Comment: One minor note: once you're *in* New Newgate Prison again, almost every action and Opportunity card there can reduce your Suspicion. Escaping New Newgate Prison, via legal means or otherwise, is guaranteed as long as you keep taking actions there. (But you'll learn to discard the more unpleasant Opportunity cards.)

Comment: An additional note: the menace locations aren't exactly punishments. Several storylines start at New Newgate and the Slow Boat, and high-level Dangerous players have an important item to acquire while exiled in the Tomb-Colonies. The Mirror-Marshes is one of the few locations where you can farm Looking Through The Eyes of Icarus, which is otherwise difficult to acquire.

Comment: Yet another additional note: going to the prison in _most_ cases causes your Criminal Record to go up, and there are no known ways to get it down. This can be inconvenient, as it reduces (and eventually eliminates) the effect of the Suspicion-reducing consumable.